# How to Extract subject Verb Object using nlp java

Tags: nlp

How to Extract SVO using NLP in java, i am new in nlp.i am currently using opennlp. but how to do in java with a perticular in java sentence.

```
LexicalizedParser lp = **new LexicalizedParser("englishPCFG.ser.gz");**
String[] sent = { "This", "is", "an", "easy", "sentence", "." };
Tree parse = (Tree) lp.apply(Arrays.asList(sent));
parse.pennPrint();
System.out.println();
TreePrint tp = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");
tp.print(parse);
```

getting an compilation error at 
new LexicalizedParser("englishPCFG.ser.gz");**
The constructor LexicalizedParser(String) is undefined

Answer (score 2):

it seems as if you are using new version of Stanford NLP parser.
in new version of this parser constructors are not used to allocate memory, instead we are having dedicated functions . you can use :

```
LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("englishPCFG.ser.gz");
```

you can use various overloads of this API.

[Stanford documentation for various overloads of loadModel](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/LexicalizedParser.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is code from the Stanford dependency parser, not from OpenNLP.  Follow the example given in ParserDemo.java (and/or ParserDemo2.java) that's included in the stanford-parser directory and make sure that your demo code and the stanford-parser.jar in your classpath are from the same version of the parser.  I suspect you are using a more recent version of the parser with older demo code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stanford CoreNLP. Check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606606/547040) for *"rough algorithm"* how to get subject-predicate-object from a sentence.

Comment: use textrunner is better api for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverb. Check answer here for "reVerb" how to get information extraction from a sentence