# Best way to make meaningful sentence from one sentence

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, tokenize

I am trying to create sub-sentences from a combined English sentence using Python. I need help in figuring out the best way and right way to do so.

I have looked into a similar question asked on this [Finding meaningful sub-sentences from a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974090/finding-meaningful-sub-sentences-from-a-sentence). The reason of asking a new question is because I wanted to rephrase the newly created sentence, once I identify a set of sub-statements from the original sentences.

Posting the minimal code, which I am currently using to do my task:

```py
def create_SLEW_Messages(req):
    print(req)

    # Pass Fail statement will be something like
    # "Verify that " + InitPart
    # first split the requirement with SHALL keyword, which is the subject
    InitPart = re.split('shall', req, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[0]

    # to get the exact word after shall
    verbWord = re.split('shall', req, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[1].split()[0]

    TempPassFailStatement1 = re.split('and', req, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[0]
    PassFailStatement1 = re.split('shall', TempPassFailStatement1, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[1]
    PassFailStatement2 = re.split('and', req, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[1].split(",")[0]

    returnPassFailStatement1 = "Verify that " + InitPart + " will " + PassFailStatement1

    print(returnPassFailStatement1)
    returnPassFailStatement2 = ""
    if verbWord in PassFailStatement2:
        returnPassFailStatement2 = "Verify that " + InitPart + " will " + PassFailStatement2
        print(returnPassFailStatement2)
    else:
        returnPassFailStatement2 = "Verify that " + InitPart + " will " + verbWord + " " + PassFailStatement2
        print(returnPassFailStatement2)

    return returnPassFailStatement1, returnPassFailStatement2
```

**Pre-condition - The statement which is provided to the above function will always have a "shall" keyword**

**Data 1 ==>** 
Input 1 - *The alpha tape shall move down for increasing xyz_alphaBeta and up for decreasing xyz_alphaBeta.*

**Ouptut (actual):**

Verify that The alpha tape will  move down for increasing xyz_alphaBeta

Verify that The alpha tape will move  up for decreasing xyz_alphaBeta.

*the above output is as per my requirement, however when I pass a sentence of similar sort and different complexity, my algo fails to detect correct sub-sentences and frames incorrect or incomplete sentences as shown below for Data 2*

**Data 2 ==>**
Input 2 - *The Minimum Data Bug shall be positioned on the alpha tape, move upwards for increasing fac_alphaV3 and downwards for decreasing fac_alphaV3.*

**Ouptut (actual):**

Verify that The Minimum Data Bug  will  be positioned on the alpha tape, move upwards for increasing fac_alphaV3

Verify that The Minimum Data Bug  will be  downwards for decreasing fac_alphaV3.

**Ouptut (required):**

Verify that The Minimum Data Bug  will  be positioned on the alpha tape, **and** move upwards for increasing fac_alphaV3

Verify that The Minimum Data Bug  will be **positioned on the alpha tape**, **and move** downwards for decreasing fac_alphaV3.

**PS. I understand, that regex or splitting technique is not a good technique in terms of splitting a language text, which can vary from one form to another. That is the reason, I am looking for some suggestions on this**

Any suggestions or inputs are welcome !!!

Comment: The technique to use will depend to some extent on the variability & predictability of the input. Do you have the full set of input statements that your program will have to handle, or will it be run on things you've never seen before?

Comment: @Michael : As of now, I don't have the full set of input statements with me.. it can be any statement, but one thing which i can guarantee is that, the statement will always have **shall** keyword. Please let me know if you have any information regarding that... One more example which I can quote is **The Full Target Indicator shall move *clockwise* for increasing values of XYZ and *counterclockwise* for decreasing values of XYZ.**